# Redirecting Specific URL pattern using REGEX

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url

I'd like to redirect the URL's

https://old-URL.com/index.php?topic={integers} to https://new-URL.com/index.php?topic={integers}

I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^\/index\.php\?topic=(.*) https://new-URL.com/ [R=301]
```

But I can't seem to get it for the life of me.

Answer (score 2):

You can not match against URL QueryString ( `?topic=val` ) in pattern of a RewriteRule. You need to use `RewriteCond` for that .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^topic=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://newurl.com/index.php?topic=%1 [L,R,NE]
```